# How to compare/merge between XIB files?

Tags: iphone

I have these two XIB files. The first one edited by my friend to add features and to other one edited by my self and add another features. My problem is how can i merge the two files? I know that XIB files are XML based and I can use some compare tools to merge it. But I think there will be some conflicts. What is the best way to compare or merge between XIB files?

Thanks a lot guys.
sasayins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open them both in BBEdit, and use BBEdit's compare functionality.

In Xcode you can combine by opening the XIB files as text file.  You will then have to do the non-trivial task of finding the differences in one and copying and pasting into the other file.

In the future, it is easier to your friend create a new XIB file that you either merge, or you just use separately, than to share and merge XIBs.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to save both versions with different names, open both in Interface Builder, and copy the changes from one version to the other. A lot of changes aren't obvious by inspection (added/removed connections, name changes, class changes, etc), but if you have an idea of what has changed, this is the easiest way to merge.